# Get a JSON from url with PHP

Tags: php

Im new to php and tried to get a json object from the twitch API to retrieve one of its values and output it.  i.e

i need to get the information from this link:  https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/USERNAME/follows/channels/CHANNELSNAME

plus i need to to something so i can modify the urls USERNAME and CHANNELSUSERNAME. I want it to be a api to call for howlong user XY is following channelXY and this will be called using nightbots $customapi function.

the date i need from the json is "created_at"

Since we were able to clear out the errorsheres the final PHP file that works if anyone encounters similiar errors:

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" . $_GET['username'] . "/follows/channels/" . $_GET['channel'];

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo $result["created_at"];
?>
```

Comment: That `}` at the end of your `$url` looks out of place

Comment: What exactly are your errors? Have your checked the apache log to find the PHP error and line number?

Comment: i think the error was because of the } apok mentioned above. fixed that and now the site shows the whole json, - progress yey!  now i just need to find a way to only print the created_at one ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code on the first line and you're not storing the result of your `json_decode` anywhere.

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" . $_GET['username'] . "/follows/channels/" . $_GET['channel'];

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo $result["created_at"];
```

You have to call the page this way `page.php?username=yeroise&channel=ceratia` in order to output the `created_at` value for this user and this channel.

In your code you're using 2 different ways to get the content of the page and you only need one (either `file_get_contents` or using CURL), I chose `file_get_contents` here as the other method adds complexity for no reason **in this case**.

Comment: I see, awesome! now the only problem that reamins is with the username and channelusername case.


i see other people using a similiar methode with this link: WEBSITE/following?channel=CHANNELNAME&user=$(touser)
so my question is how can i edit my php file to have this aswell?  with adding the channelname and giving the user with the $(touser) i need the php script to recognize and somehow alter the url to fetch like 
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/THEUSERNAMEPROVIDED/follows/channels/THECHANNELNAMESPROVIDED";

Comment: tried that. Sadly the page stays white without any output.i edit the question with the actual .php file to help you identify any mistakes i might added ^^

Comment: Are you SURE you're calling the page correctly? You HAVE to specify the username and the channel name in the URL like that: `page.php?username=yeroise&channel=ceratia`

Comment: It's hard to tell since you're not displaying the errors, but I would say that cross-domain URL opening in blocked on your host. Make sure that `allow_url_fopen` is **not** set to `false` in your `php.ini` file. Also try to enable errors so that you can know where the issue comes from exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118819/discussion-between-user3220962-and-antoineb).